# Test Win8 App hosted in Azure Compute Emulator on Tablet

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I have a two web application in Visual Studio 2012 running in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator (using IIS Web Service, not Express). Additionally I have a Windows 8 App in another Visual Studio instance which uses both azure web applications. This combination works fine on the same machine.

For presentation purposes I'd like to run the app on a Windows RT Tablet. Therefore I use the remote debugging tool to run the app on the tablet. Running the app is not the problem. But I didn't found a possibility to connect to the web applications from the tablet. The azure Emulator generates URLs like 127.0.0.X:81 but the tablet cannot resolve this address.

Is there a workaround to solve my problem? A way to run the azure application with the IP address of my dev machine? Or is it possible to create a kind of a proxy running on the dev machine which forwards requests from the tablet to the azure application?

I've seen a possible solution running fiddler as a reverse proxy. This does not work for me because fiddler seems to listen only on one port. But I need two.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to configure the Azure Emulator endpoint.

Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778456/accessing-azure-emulator-from-another-device) for more information.